# Display a Value from a Specific DB Field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out what I've got going on here thats not working - I'm using RsTicketsPro and I'm trying to pull a specific value from their custom fields section in the database. I reached out to their support and this is what they recommended:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `value` FROM #__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values WHERE `ticket_id`='".$item->id."' AND `custom_field_id`=7");
echo $db->loadResult();
```

Ok so I adjusted their code to pop this into place in a table to display this specific value:

```
<td align="center" class="rst_cell_assigned center">
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT 'value' FROM #__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values WHERE 'ticket_id'='".$item->id."' AND 'custom_field_id'=4");
echo $db->loadResult();
?>
</td>
```

I updated the custom field id value to match with the corresponding field I want to pull from my database, but when I view it on the front end, it just displays blank - no error message or anything.

Anybody spot anything I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: CURRENT CODE IM WORKING WITH**

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(`value`);
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values'));
$query->where($db->quoteName(`ticket_id`)." = ".$db->quote('".$item->id."' AND `custom_field_id`=4"));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
echo $query;
echo $db->getErrorMsg();
?>
```

**note** so this one now does not even load the page any longer, haha. #fail

[image: Table being used]

Comment: Have you echoed $item->id to make sure that it exists as a value? Have you looked in the database manually to make sure that there is a result? Whilst it should work to just whack the full query into $db->setQuery, the lack of escaping variables would make me nervous - look at https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase for tider ways to create a query string.

Comment: Just edited my original post to include my new code that I worked out through that page you recommended, however the page wont even load now using this - anything look out of place to you or anyone else?

Comment: When you say a "lack of escaping variables" what do you mean exactly? Closing the database string? Here is my final code - does this look ok? or would I be at risk?

*See above for the code - couldnt figure out how to format it correctly on a comment. (new to the site here)

Comment: I meant escaping strings -  https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Secure_strings - ie wrapping the $db->quote() around the variable.  It usually isn't going to matter, but it's good practise to always do as it prevents possible sql injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a direct copy paste, you have a mysql error:

`SELECT 'value' FROM #__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values WHERE 'ticket_id'='".$item->id."' AND 'custom_field_id'=4`

`'value'` and `'ticket_id'` should have back ticks not quotes around it.

I suspect if you ran `echo $db->getErrorMsg();` right after `echo $db->loadResult();`, it would tell you there is a MySql error.

On the 2nd part where you use the query wrapper, can you post the output of `echo $query;`?

Comment: Updated the code again correcting the back ticks and added the error message echo but nothing is loading still. (you can see it above again)

Comment: How close was I?

Comment: You definitely got me going back to the original code that they sent over to me to have another look at it. For some reason my brain never went to the back ticks - is that only when we're referencing a column specifically?

Comment: Backtick are for referencing a column name. Quote are for columm values.

Comment: Gracias!!! that makes sense.

Comment: Throw me an up vote if you don't mind :)

Comment: I did but I'm still a noob so it said it doesnt display it until I reach a certain level.

Comment: I forgot about that. I just stated as well. Working on the reputation so I can comment.

Comment: I've got a new one maybe you can help me with - very similar: [link](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/display-entry-when-referencing-2-tables)

Comment: David, you really shouldn't do "raw" sql through jdatabase, you should use the query builder and quoting to keep things secure and abstracted.

See Selecting data using JDatabase https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the issue is due to your select statement missing quoteName
and a malformed where statement

you should also use chaining (and qn alias for quoteName q for quote)

This should be the right way to do queries using the Joomla query builder syntax

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('value'))
      ->from($db->qn('#__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values'))
      ->where($db->qn('ticket_id') . " = " . $db->q($item->id))
      ->where($db->qn('custom_field_id') . " = " . $db->q(4));
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();
```

- See [Selecting data using JDatabase](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)
- See [Inserting, Updating and Removing data using JDatabase](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase)
- See [Joomla coding standards](http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards/) (which includes a small part on best
  practices for JDatabase queries in the PHP section)

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh! I got it!!! I went back to the original code and was able to get it to work properly!

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `value` FROM #__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values WHERE `ticket_id`='".$item->id."' AND `custom_field_id`=4");
$result = $db->loadResult();
echo $db->loadResult();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Joomla's PHP Coding Standards say:

> Table names and table column names should always be enclosed in the
>   quoteName() method to escape the table name and table columns. Field
>   values checked in a query should always be enclosed in the quote()
>   method to escape the value before passing it to the database. Integer
>   field values checked in a query should also be type cast to (int).

Toeing this line too often results in ugly and bloated code, while unnecessarily calling quoting methods.

Because none of the table or column names actually need quoting, and you should cast integer variables as integer type before writting them into the query, this is what I would recommend...

*note `value` is a MySQL keyword, but not a Reserved Keyword, so it doesn't require backticking. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-V

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("value")
    ->from("#__rsticketspro_custom_fields_values")
    ->where([
        "ticket_id = " . (int)$item->id,
        "custom_field_id = 4"
    ]);
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

- the WHERE clause is happy to receive an array of conditions
- method chaining can start from the `getQuery()` method to avoid writing `$query` at the start of each line
- there is no point in quoting or casting the static value `4`

The above snippet is as secure as it can be written while using Joomla's query building methods without needless quoting calls.