# Display Entry when referencing 2 Tables

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql

Ok this is building on what I was previously working on in my last post:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `profile_value` FROM #__user_profiles WHERE `user_id`='customer_id' AND `profile_key`='profile.address1'");
$result = $db->loadResult();
echo $db->loadResult();
?>
```

So in this situation, I have to reference **customer_id** from a different table than the rest of this. How would I go about pointing just that one field that is located in this other table (**rsticketspro_tickets**)

Or am I going about this in the completely wrong way? I'm trying to place this code to pull an address from a users profile on a "View Ticket" screen. So the customer_id is what is referenced on that page I believe, so maybe its already a variable?

**NEW CODE**

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `profile_value` FROM #__user_profiles WHERE `user_id`='rsticketspro_tickets.customer_id' AND `profile_key`='profile.address1'");
$result = $db->loadResult();
echo $db->loadResult();
?>
```

**NEW NEW CODE**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('a.profile_value'))
  ->from($db->qn('#__user_profiles'), 'a')
  ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__rsticketspro_tickets', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->qn('a.user_id') . " = " . $db->q(b.customer_id) . ')')
->where($db->qn('a.profile_key') . " = " . $db->q('b.address1'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

This might help, but I cant seem to see whats wrong in everything at the moment still.

**TABLE:** *#__user_profiles*

**COLUMNS:** *user_id, profile_key, profile_value*

**PROFILE_KEY VALUE:** *profile.address1*

**TABLE:** *#__rsticketspro_tickets*

**COLUMNS:** *customer_id*

Comment: Ok so again I'm working on it and identified kind of how to do it but I must have some issues with syntax maybe. New code listed above.

Comment: You need a JOIN I think. You need data from multiple tables combined together?

Comment: No - I think the issue is that I need to find the variable for customer_id - in the other example I had, this was something like `".$item->id."` - but I cant seem to find the equivalent for customer_id.

Comment: New new code looks a lot closer. Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Yea - i think that the tables are wrong somehow. i'll edit the original post to show the tables format a little better somehow.

Comment: Can you run `echo $query,'<br>',$db->getErrorMsg();` right after `echo $db->loadResult()`;, it would tell us the actually query produced and if there is a mysql error.

Comment: This was also displayed before I added the error message entry, but this is what it was saying: 1054 - Unknown column 'a.profile_value' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT `a`.`profile_value` FROM `#__user_profiles` INNER JOIN `#__rsticketspro_tickets` AS `b` ON (`a`.`user_id` = 'bcustomer_id') WHERE `a`.`profile_key` = 'b.profile.address1'

Comment: @BrandonSjelin I am currently on a quest to resolve all open sql-based Joomla questions. If you can provide a minimal sample of the two relevant db tables in a SQLFiddle and your expected resultset, I am certain that I can provide a direct and educational solution for you.  Please take the time to offer these details so that future researchers can learn from this page.

Comment: @BrandonSjelin I am still happy to take the time to craft you a direct solution.  Please comment @ me if you can possibly deliver the relevant data for me to play with.

Answer (score 3):

You should review how to use JDatabase for queries, what you wrote is basically a RAW SQL statement and left off the join for the second table. Here is the correct structure with chaining (it should work if your table columns and variables are named correctly). In either case, see the references for example on using JDatabase.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('a.profile_value'))
  ->from($db->qn('#__user_profiles'), 'a')
  ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__rsticketspro_tickets', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->qn('a.user_id') . " = " . $db->q(b.customer_id) . ')')
  ->where($db->qn('a.user_id') . " = " . $db->q($customer_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

Assuming you already have the customer ID the join is totally unnecessary unless you need data from the second table.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('a.profile_value'))
  ->from($db->qn('#__user_profiles'), 'a')
  ->where($db->qn('a.user_id') . " = " . $db->q($item->customer_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

**additional code needed to extract the address1 data from the $result**

- See [Selecting data using JDatabase](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)
- See [Inserting, Updating and Removing data using JDatabase](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase)
- See [Joomla coding standards](http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards/) (which includes a small part on best
  practices for JDatabase queries in the PHP section)

Comment: This is what I got when trying that:  1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `#__user_profiles` INNER JOIN `#__rsticketspro_tickets` AS `b` ON (Ar' at line 2 SQL=SELECT FROM `#__user_profiles` INNER JOIN `#__rsticketspro_tickets` AS `b` ON (Array = 'bcustomer_id') WHERE Array = 'baddress1'

Comment: I don't have your table names and column names so I can't fix that issue.

All I posted was to show you the correct format for the structure, use the links provided with your specific data to implement it for your use case. There just isn't enough information in what you provided for me to provide fully functioning code. (plus you should read the references I provided so you know what to do the next time)

Comment: Also Double check what you copied, there was a quote hanging out at the end of the `->where()` statement. A misplaced quote, or a missing or extra bracket can break a SQL query.

Comment: Ya I saw the extra quote and that's when I got the syntax error message. I'll play with it more in a little while and read the material too! :)

Comment: Just noticed there was some wrong and missing tick marks. I have corrected that now.

Comment: Thats sooo close - Its just having issues with the table names or column names now - I listed the tables/columns above in the original post now, maybe its just the a/b getting mixed up?

Comment: Where is the address1 line in the where coming from? Your table column list doesn't list it.

Comment: Sorry! It's a value under the column profile_key. I updated the list above.

Comment: Ok since the address1 is part of the profile_value you will need to get the result then process that to get the portion of the result that you need.  Basically your where is the same as the on portion of the join.

Comment: Do you have the customer_id before you start your query? If so, we can simplify this and the join becomes unnecessary since you already have the necessary value to match to your user_id

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what the component is generating - i cant find any type of variable for the customer_id within any of the pages though I would assume its there somewhere. When working on another similar issue for the same component the developers gave me `.$item` that i used to reference the ticket. I tried just guessing for `.$customer` maybe but no luck so far. Example: **WHERE `ticket_id`='".$item->id."'**

Comment: That's where a local development environment and xdebug become your friends. 

Your other option is to ask RSJoomla (the developers) what the variable is.

Comment: I messaged them but they are suuuuuper slow at responding - so we'll see if I get it in a few days - IF they decide to disclose it, I had to pull teeth to get the other info, haha

Comment: All depends on what they are currently working on. I've made some corrections to the queries above.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I think I might have something that works!!! Its kind of a combination of all of the stuff you guys helped me with:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('profile_value'))
      ->from($db->qn('#__user_profiles'))
      ->where($db->qn('user_id') . " = " . $db->q($user->id))
      ->where($db->qn('profile_key') . " = " . $db->q('profile.address1'));
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();
echo $db->loadResult();
```

Only problem is I'm putting this into the field with the user profiles, so ANY person that replies is going to get the address showing up instead of just the original customer_id which is what we really want, but all I was able to find in the other code was the `$user->id` reference. Also, it seems to be putting my result in quotes for some reason when displaying.